# Correlation between columns of different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have many dataframes. They all share the same column structure `"date", "open_position_profit", "more columns..."`.

```
    date    open_position_profit col2   col3
0   2008-04-01  -260.0  1   290.0
1   2008-04-02  -340.0  1   -60.0
2   2008-04-03  100.0   1   40.0
3   2008-04-04  180.0   1   -90.0
4   2008-04-05  0.0 0   0.0 0.0 1
```

Although `"date"` is present in all dataframes, they might or might not have the same count (some dates might be in one dataframe but not the other).

I want to compute a correlation matrix of the columns `"open_position_profit"` of all these dataframes.

I've tried this

```
dfs = [df1[["date", "open_position_profit"]], df2[["date", "open_position_profit"]], ...]
pd.concat(dfs).groupby('date', as_index=False).corr()
```

But this gives me a series of the correlation for each cell:

```
                           open_position_profit
0    open_position_profit                   1.0
1    open_position_profit                   1.0
2    open_position_profit                   1.0
3    open_position_profit                   1.0
4    open_position_profit                   NaN
```

I want the correlation for the entire time series, not each single cell. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, it is necessary to do outer join first. The following code does outer join by `date` key. The missing value can be represented by `NaN`.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date', how='outer')
         date  open_position_profit_x  open_position_profit_y  ... ...
0  2019-01-01       ... 
1  2019-01-02       ...
2  2019-01-03       ...
3  2019-01-04       ...
```

Then you can calculate the correlation with the new DataFrame.

```
df.corr()
                         open_position_profit_x  open_position_profit_y  ... ...
open_position_profit_x   1.000000                0.866025        
open_position_profit_y   0.866025                1.000000  
...                      1.000000                1.000000  
...                      1.000000                1.000000
```

See: [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)